# Issues with displaying answer of calculations in java/html Grade Calculator

Tags: javascript, java, html

I seem to be having issues with the display of the answers, I need a Letter grade in one box and the number grade in the other when the calculations button is clicked.

But neither wants to display, I have tried `onclick` several ways but nothing works.

I have done what I can and am so confused as to why its not working.

```js
function calculategrades() {
  var letterGrade = "F";
  if (number <= 59)
    letterGrade = "F";
  else if (number >= 60 && number <= 66)
    letterGrade = "D";
  else if (number >= 67 && number <= 69)
    letterGrade = "D+";
  else if (number >= 70 && number <= 76)
    letterGrade = "C";
  else if (number >= 77 && number <= 79)
    letterGrade = "C+";
  else if (number >= 80 && number <= 86)
    letterGrade = "B";
  else if (number >= 87 && number <= 89)
    letterGrade = "B+";
  else if (number >= 90 && number <= 100)
    letterGrade = "A";
  return letterGrade;
}

function grade() {
  var test1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('test').value * 0.20);
  var test2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('test2').value * 0.20);
  var finalexam = parseFloat(document.getElementById('exam').value * 0.30);
  var labs = parseFloat(document.getElementById('labs').value * 0.25);
  var project = parseFloat(document.getElementById('project').value * 0.25);
  var quizzes = parseFloat(document.getElementById('quiz').value * 0.5);
  var total = test1 + test2 + finalexam + labs + project + quizzes;
  var display = document.getElementById('numbergrade');
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Score</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Test 1</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="test" id="test" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test 2</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="test2" id="test3" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Final Exam</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="exam" id="exam" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Labs</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="labs" id="labs" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Project</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="project" id="project" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quizzes</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="quiz" id="quiz" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" style="text-align: center"><input type="button" name="total" id="total" value="Calculate" onclick="grades()" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th><input type="text" name="numbergrade" id="numbergrade" /></th>
        <th><input type="text" name="lettergrade" id="lettergrade" /></th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>


</form>
```

Comment: 1. You never pass a grade number to your function calculategrades() or call it from your button

Comment: You mean call the function? Such as onclick="calculategrades()" ? And  pass a grade number?

Comment: Btw this is JavaScript and html not java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are your fixed codes

```js
function calculateGrades(number) {
  var letterGrade = "F";
  if (number <= 59)
    letterGrade = "F";
  else if (number >= 60 && number <= 66)
    letterGrade = "D";
  else if (number >= 67 && number <= 69)
    letterGrade = "D+";
  else if (number >= 70 && number <= 76)
    letterGrade = "C";
  else if (number >= 77 && number <= 79)
    letterGrade = "C+";
  else if (number >= 80 && number <= 86)
    letterGrade = "B";
  else if (number >= 87 && number <= 89)
    letterGrade = "B+";
  else if (number >= 90 && number <= 100)
    letterGrade = "A";
  return letterGrade;
}

function grade() {
  var test1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('test').value * 0.20);
  var test2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('test3').value * 0.20);
  var finalexam = parseFloat(document.getElementById('exam').value * 0.30);
  var labs = parseFloat(document.getElementById('labs').value * 0.25);
  var project = parseFloat(document.getElementById('project').value * 0.25);
  var quizzes = parseFloat(document.getElementById('quiz').value * 0.5);
  var total = test1 + test2 + finalexam + labs + project + quizzes;
  return total;
}

function showGrades() {
  var number = grade();
  var letter = calculateGrades(number);
  document.getElementById('numbergrade').value = number;
  document.getElementById('lettergrade').value = letter;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Score</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Test 1</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="test" id="test" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test 2</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="test2" id="test3" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Final Exam</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="exam" id="exam" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Labs</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="labs" id="labs" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Project</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="project" id="project" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quizzes</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="quiz" id="quiz" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" style="text-align: center"><input type="button" name="total" id="total" value="Calculate" onclick="showGrades()" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th><input type="text" name="numbergrade" id="numbergrade" /></th>
        <th><input type="text" name="lettergrade" id="lettergrade" /></th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>


</form>
```

You had mistyped a lot and also you never called the function calculateGrades and did not accept argument in calculateGrades so you were using some global variable "number" and you did not set the result of function grade as value to numbergrade

Comment: nice work Petr I was just muddling my way thru that missing function

Comment: THAT WORKED! Thanks. I initially added the number but it didn't work. It does now!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, just a guess? do to the way you code is posted I can not test.

change

```
var display = document.getElementById('numbergrade');
```

to

```
document.getElementById("numbergrade").innerHTML = total;
```

then call calculategrades() passing total into it so it has something to work with.

then change

```
return letterGrade;
```

to

```
document.getElementById("lettergrade").innerHTML = lettergrade;
```